# Xcode - Deleted derived data and screwed up the frameworks

Tags: xcode

I deleted the derived data and my frameworks are now messed up. Even though I removed and reinstalled the pod, xcworkspace simply refuses to detect it, worse it no longer creates the links and now it's all in red.

[image: Click to see image]

Really at a loss here.

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question but I'm self taught.

Latest update: I managed to get the app running again by changing "Build Active Architecture Only" from NO to YES. Not sure if this is the right way to do things but it works for me.

Still the frameworks are in red and I am worried Apple will not accept this project for it's store.

Anyone can help me with fixing it?

[Progress @ Day 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2doUd.png)

Comment: What happens when you try to build?

Comment: Quit xcode, run "pod install" again. Open your project, see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hey guys, it tells me that RSKImageCropper is not found. Which obviously isn't the case. I also can't seem to find any resource to learn more about this problem, you guys know of any?